# How to BLOCK specific column in the GridView

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView and when an USER clicks on UPDATE I want to block couple of columns so that User cannot edit those columns.

How should I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the `ReadOnly` property value of those columns to `true`.

Answer (score 1):

select those columns in "AspxGridView Columns Editor" and set ReadOnly property to true